# Use tekst from table depending on number in other table using Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I feel stupid asking this, but I really need an excample on how to get a value of a field in one table (in the end in my report) depending on a value of a field from an other table in Access.
So I have (for excample) a table:
Products and in my report I do a formule using the value of price (field of Products) and adding to that I must have the value of the field VAT-Type (a nummeric var, in the table VATS) depending on what is there in the record (of the one in the table Products) in the field VAT-Sort, also a nummeric var that must meet one of the values used in the field VAT-Type).
So in the report I must have something like:
Product: X Count Price'=(price+21%)'

where 21% comes from the dependensy between the field VAT-Type and VAT-Sort.

I know I can do something like **result**=select 'VAT-Sort' from 'VATS' WHERE 'VAT-Sort' = or equals 'VAT-type' 
But how do I use it in a report of Access to get the right result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DLookUp](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786):

```
Numeric data type:

DlookUp("Value","Vats","Vat_Type=" & Vat_Sort)

Text data type:

DlookUp("Value","Vats","Vat_Type='" & Vat_Sort & "'")
```

Or you can base your report on a query, say:

```
SELECT Value, Other, Field, names FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Vats
ON Products.VAT_Sort = Vats.Vat_Type
```

Edit re comments

[image: change report record source]

Comment: Thanks, and how do I use this in a report, so how do I say it has to be the value of the Query?

Comment: You can set the record source of a report to a saved query or an sql string, then all the fields will be available; you can set a textbox control source to `=DlookUp(...`

Comment: And how do I use just the SELECT query part into a new query in Access? I can only use wizzard or Query deziner it seems...?

Comment: You can use the query designer to build the new query. Add the table with your data and the table with Vat and then drag the matching field from the first table to the Vat table to create a join. Next add all the fields you want to the design grid. Note that you can paste accurate SQL into SQL view or the query design window, but the sql above is only an example, so build the query using the usual design view.

Comment: and to make it a litle bit differend now (I didn't thought of it earlier), I have a field called "Value" (in the table VATS) that I will use as actual end value ro use in my report. So It should find the result value "Value" in VATS with the equal value from "VAT_Type"(of the table Products) in "VAT_Sort"(of the table VATS), so something like 21%

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you have a lot of rows with different Vat rates? If so, use a query. Do you only need one Vat rate, then you can use DLookup.

Comment: I have than one VAT rate, (now 3) and need to use per product result listed in my report only one value. So per product the price inclusive VAT. But in an other bit of the report I will give the product price without VAT.

Comment: So product X $12.10, product Y $36.30 and the somewhere else in the report± Product X $10 and prodyct Y $30

Comment: What part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: I made the query, but it gives me more than one result now when I test it. Maybe I need to study some more on it :) I will for now try to enter it in my report.

Comment: When I try now to add it to my already existing report, I can not find the option to use the query. Do you know where to look?

Comment: It sounds as if you have not got the join right. If you only need one Vat rate, just use DlookUp. Make a textbox equal to `=DlookUp(as shown above)`, then you can say in another textbox , for example, `=TextBox1 * Textbox2`

Comment: OK, and if I want to use the SQL query (whe I got it right) to use as a value (just because I already come this far and preferely want to use one methode) ;). Can you explain how to add this in design mode in the report? By the way, thanks for your help so far and such a rapid respons.

Comment: If you create the query and it works the way you want, you can save it as say, ReportQuery, then open the report in design view and change the report's Record Source on the data tab of the property sheet to ReportQuery.

Comment: Thnx a lot, I will do that and report back later. Really appriciate your help

Comment: Hi, its me again. Can't get it right. I got so far: (not translated this time): table "Producten" and within that NaamProduct and BTWType. And an other table "BTW-Typen" and within it BTW-Soort and Waarde.   I tried translating your query in to Dutch, the language it its made it, but I can't get the Join syntax right.

Comment: BTWType is a numeric var 0-2 and BTW-Soort also a numeric var 0-2 and Waarde is 0 or 0,21 or 0,06

Comment: Have you tried using the query design window? I am afraid it is very late here.

Comment: I also have under "Producten" NaamProduct (nameofproduct) and PrijsPerEenheid (price per one product)

Comment: OK, I tried it, but I get this query: SELECT [BTW-Typen].Waarde
FROM Producten INNER JOIN [BTW-Typen] ON (Producten.BTWType=[BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort]) AND (Producten.BTWType=[BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort]);
But when I run it I see all the vars under each other but when I use it in my report, it is empty

Comment: To test some more, I used: SELECT [BTW-Typen].Id, [BTW-Typen].Waarde, [BTW-Typen].Omschrijving, [BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort], [Producten].NaamProduct, [Producten].ProductId
FROM Producten INNER JOIN [BTW-Typen] ON (Producten.BTWType=[BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort]) AND (Producten.BTWType=[BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort])
WHERE [Producten].ProductId=2; to get one result. The result gives me the correct value's of that record. Ofcourse I can not use this part pf the query with all the extra vars, but maybe tomorrow you can look at it some more. Good night.

Comment: What happens when you save `SELECT [BTW-Typen].Waarde FROM Producten INNER JOIN [BTW-Typen] ON (Producten.BTWType=[BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort]) AND (Producten.BTWType=[BTW-Typen].[BTW-Soort])` and then use the report wizard to create a report?